# How to return value from window.open in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, callback

In order to return a value from `window.open` which uses `postMessage` to post some data, I used `window.addEventListener` in parent window (opener) and faced a serious issue regarding the callback event, which never gets executed on Internet Explorer 11 and always executes on Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

Below is the basic code to illustrate the problem I'm facing:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <!--  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;IE=9;IE=10;IE=11;IE=edge"> -->
      <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>
      <p id="message"></p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <script>
         var messageEle = document.getElementById('message');
         function receiveMessage(e) {
             messageEle.innerHTML = "Message Received: " + e.data;
         }
         window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);
         function myFunction() {
             window.open("child.html", "test", "top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <p>Child Window</p>
      <a href="javascript:;" onclick="sendMessage()">Send Message</a>
      <script>
         function sendMessage(){
             window.opener.postMessage("test", "*");
             window.close();
         }

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to open the child window as an iFrame!

Use the `window.parent.postMessage("message", "*");` in child window to post the message to parent window, and the parent needs to listen to the event using `window.onmessage`.

Below is the working code example on Internet Explorer:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Parent Window</h1>
      <p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>
      <h3 id="message"></h3>
      <iframe src="child.html" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
      <script>
         window.onmessage = function (e) {
          var messageEle = document.getElementById('message');
              messageEle.innerHTML = "Message Received from child window: " + e.data;
         };
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**child.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Child Window</h1>
      <a href="javascript:;" onclick="sendMessage()">Send Message to parent window</a>
      <script>
         function sendMessage(){
             window.parent.postMessage("Hello", "*");
             window.close();
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```